# About jQuery Themeroller themes, where can I find more?

Tags: jquery, themes, themeroller

I found jQuery Themeroller very useful, except the resources I found below, where can I find more Themeroller-Ready themes (except roll out my own)

- http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
- http://wijmo.com/theming/

Which better have more than 1 theme and support CDN already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where can I find more Themeroller-Ready themes

All Default Themes are right in [jQueryUI Themeroller Dashboard](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), simple click in the second tab, called **Gallery**.

[image]

You can download all of them and use in your web pages.

Comment: why do you want more? choose one and press `edit` then, simple change anything like colors, borders, font and save the new theme ... there you go, a brand new theme!

Comment: because my design looks bad, so I like to have the idea from others